# Define an array with enum variable as array size

Tags: c, arrays, enums

What does it mean to define an array with enum variable as array size?

For example I have the following code:

```
typedef enum
{
  D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_0 = 0x0,
  D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_1,   

  D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS

}E_ROM_RDE_GROUPS;

U_08 pPlaneCopy[D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS];
```

I don't understand it...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question gave me an idea how to solve my problem, so +1 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that enumeration values are compile-time constant. The other thing is that enumeration values (unless initialized to a specific value) increases. So in your case `D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_0` is equal to `0`, `D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_1` is equal to `1` and `D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS` is equal to `2`.

This means that when you declare the array, it's basically the same thing as

```
U_08 pPlaneCopy[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a techique often used to define an array that is in some way related to the values in an enum.  For a simple example:

```
enum  {
   ZERO, 
   ONE,
   TWO,
   THREE,
   MAX_VALUE //has value of 4
};
```

because the natural value of an enumerated element starts at zero, and increments by one for each member, the final value will always be useful to initialize an array, of any type (`strings`, `ints`, `floats`, etc) for a number of elements equal to that final value.  eg.

```
int numbers[MAX_VALUE];//an array with 4 elements
int i;
```

You can then use MAX_VALUE to guarantee treating the array in a loop without going beyond the bounds of the array, eg. something like:

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_VALUE;i++)//will loop 4 times
{
    numbers[i]=i;//assigned a value equal to its namesake, for i < MAX_VALUE
}
```

Given this explanation, the enum in your original post is simply being initialized with a value of 2:

```
U_08 pPlaneCopy[D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS];
```

is the same as

```
U_08 pPlaneCopy[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

The enum value D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS is actually an integer value, in your case: 2. So you are defining an array with two elements. Probably the two elements will be accessed by the indices : D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_0 and D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_1

Answer (score 1):

An unsigned integer is automatically assigned to each enum elements if not explicitly specified otherwise. Thus, with your enum declaration, `D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_0` equals to `0`, `D_ROM_RDE_GROUP_1` equals to `1`, and `D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS` equals to 2.

Thus, the declaration

```
U_08 pPlaneCopy[D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS];
```

is equivalent to

```
U_08 pPlaneCopy[2];
```

Which means, you declared an array with one `U_08` element corresponding to each possible value in `E_ROM_RDE_GROUPS` assuming `D_ROM_RDE_MAX_GROUPS` is not a value used otherwise.

Comment: +1: but `unsigned`? An `enum` is an `int`, not `unsigned int`.